# Scala, paging without max

Tags: scala

I have to query an API with pagination. But because the API is weird I have to query it until the response is empty (contains no items).

Actually it is done in Java with a do-while :

```
do { 
  objects = doQuery(from);
  from += 200
} while ( !objects.isEmpty() )
```

But I would like to convert it in scala. My first idea is to use a stream with a step and takeWhile :

```
Stream.iterate(0)(_+200)
  .map( from => doQuery(from) )
  .takeWhile( objects -> !objects.isEmpty )
```

But another changes make `doQuery` returns a `Future`. Thus I cannot do the test in takeWhile and have no best idea on how to do it (maybe a recursive call).
Hopefully this new code will be into an Akka actor that will tell another for each object (no need to return anything)

Comment: do/while is OK in scala, as long as you do not expose mutable state.

Comment: @dveim Thanks. Yes I know that, just willing to use a more 'functional' style.

Comment: You want a stream which scans over side effects, so I'd go fs2 or akka-streams, might be a bit painful over stdlib stream.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you `Stream[Future[(Boolean, T)]]`, where the first time will be `false` as soon as the rest will be empty. Not sure how to do the `takeWhile` without blocking.

```
Stream.iterate(0)(_+200)
  .scanLeft(Future((true, List[Int]())))({case (prev, from) =>
      prev.flatMap({case (cont, _) =>
        if(cont) {
          doQuery(from).map(res => (res.isEmpty, res.toList))
        } else {
          Future((false, List()))
        }
      })
    })
```